# Can I use JSNice with ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I tried to send a JavaScript file to [JSNice](http://jsnice.org/) but it sent back the following errors:

```
Error compiling input:

Line 175: Parse error. getters are not supported in older versions of JavaScript. If you are targeting newer versions of JavaScript, set the appropriate language_in option.
Line 193: Parse error. getters are not supported in older versions of JavaScript. If you are targeting newer versions of JavaScript, set the appropriate language_in option.
Line 193: Parse error. setters are not supported in older versions of JavaScript. If you are targeting newer versions of JavaScript, set the appropriate language_in option.
```

I tried a whole bunch of variations on `language_in` but couldn't get it to work. Is there a way to use JSNice with getter/setters?

An example curl:

```
curl -v 'http://jsnice.org/beautify?pretty=1&rename=1&types=1&suggest=0&language_in=ecmascript6' -d @output.js
```

Comment: You should just ask their support

Comment: What did make you think that it supports ES6 in the first place? JS tools aren't ready for that, even ES6 minifier.is not there yet.

Comment: Nothing in particular. I only asked here on the off chance someone knew how. I've sent them an email and will see what they say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad to announce that recently we released a new version of [JSNice.org](http://jsnice.org/) that finally supports ES6 standard.

The full list of newly-supported features:

- Support for ECMASCRIPT 6;
- Built-in packers detector;
- Possibility to transpile not yet supported code;
- Increased prediction accuracy;
- Ability to provide direct feedback on JSNice predictions.

You are welcome to try it. Please do not forget to leave your feedback on each individual prediction and fill a [general feedback form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/17O4-FwAK2kC5bKMrI9FiKn2ioZTME0dSqO2Ve2ZJPTE/edit). Your feedback will help us to improve.

Answer (score 0):

I emailed the maintainers of the site and received this response:

> We do not allow setting parameters to the JSNice compiler at this time.
>
> Regards,
> Veselin